# Push Notification Details showing N/A in back4app parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I'm using back4app for my android application and sending notification through them. On my Dashboard when I click on past pushes the details such as whether the user opened the notification or dismissed it. It says this should be done automatically.

Here is a
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl8bb.png)

Comment: Hi,
N/A show your deliver push notification not open. 
You can send a push to your own device then open push notification, it will change to a number. 
hope! i will help you

Comment: Hi , My delieved push notification status is different , the N/A is for the open rate, I have updated my screenshot, have a look at it and you will understand what i am talking about